# DexArchiveMergerException while generating signed apk

Tags: android, apk, signed

I have an DexArchiveMergerException when try to build **SIGNED** android apk. It happens only with signed apk. If I debug app or build not signed apk, everything works well.

I've already tried to clean project, invalidate cache and restart, delete build folder, but nothing helps. It's understandable that the thuth is over dependencies. And it's refers to MultiDex. But what particulary I don't know.

Can you help me with this please?

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.incubasys.tahlilaty"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_PREFIX", ""
            buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_SERVER", ""
            buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_PROTOCOL", ""
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_PREFIX", ""
            buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_SERVER", ""
            buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_PROTOCOL", ""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = "28.0.0"
    supportMutliDexLibraryVersion = "1.0.3"
    supportDesignVersion = "1.0.0"
    constraintLayoutVersion = "1.1.3"
    flexBoxVersion = "1.0.0"
    googleGmsServiceVersion = "16.0.1"
    ciceroneVersion = "4.0.2"
    rxJavaVersion = "2.1.6"
    rxAndroidVersion = "2.0.1"
    daggerVersion = "2.14.1"
    retrofit2Version = "2.4.0"
    okhttp3Version = "3.11.0"
    gsonVersion = "2.8.5"
    lombokVersion = "1.18.0"
    androidAnnotationsVersion = "4.5.2"
    accountKitVersion = "4.34.0"
    firebaseCoreVersion = "16.0.4"
    firebaseMessagingVersion = "17.3.4"
    moxyVersion = "1.5.5"
    lottieVersion = "2.7.0"
    timberVersion = "4.7.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:$supportMutliDexLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android:flexbox:$flexBoxVersion"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$googleGmsServiceVersion"

    //Cicerone
    implementation "ru.terrakok.cicerone:cicerone:$ciceroneVersion"

    // RxJava and RxAndroid
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"

    //Dagger2
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"

    //Retrofit 2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2Version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit2Version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit2Version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3Version"

    //Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"

    //Joda
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"

    //AndroidAnnotations
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$androidAnnotationsVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$androidAnnotationsVersion"
    kapt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$androidAnnotationsVersion"

    //Account Kit
    implementation "com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:$accountKitVersion"

    //Firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseCoreVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseMessagingVersion"

    //Moxy
    implementation "com.arello-mobile:moxy:$moxyVersion"
    implementation "com.arello-mobile:moxy-android:$moxyVersion"
    implementation "com.arello-mobile:moxy-app-compat:$moxyVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:$moxyVersion"

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    // Timber
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timberVersion"

    // EventBus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And a project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The error is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\0, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\1, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\release\0
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2143.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\0, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\1, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\release\0
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:225)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\0, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\1, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\release\0
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:221)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\0, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\1, C:\Android_projects\Tahlilaty\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\release\0
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:67)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: You can try it.
In manifest file <Application> tag add below line.
 tools:replace="allowBackup"

Comment: Thank you for trying help me, but unfortunately your decision doesn't work. I've just checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision was in Lombok library: decreasing version to 1.16.20 solved the problem.